# Mapbox - Image on a map - image import from url throws error

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox

I am trying to plot a mapbox map with an image overlay. I specify the url and try to run the code, but it throws an error when I inspect the .html in Chrome:

```
mapbox-gl.js:87 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at blob:null/28b7e67a-c552-4109-88b1-d8fefaff6ace may not be loaded.
at e._prepareImage (https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.js:87:2682)
at e.prepare (https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.js:87:2212)
at o.prepare (https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.js:99:1982)
at Painter.renderPass (https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.js:72:4748)
at Painter.render (https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.js:72:4274)
at e._render (https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.js:207:11604)
```

This is the code I am running, which is throwing the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoia3Z5YiIsImEiOiJjaXUwMHEwcmgwMDAxMnlvM3NzMm0xbGozIn0.JL_eeNZL_lDoJxijNqFPoA';
var mapStyle = {
    "version": 8,
    "name": "Dark",
    "sources": {
        "mapbox": {
            "type": "vector",
            "url": "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v6"
        },
        "overlay": {
            "type": "image",
            "url": "i.imgur.com/ciCbAHY.png",
            "coordinates": [
                [-80.425, 46.437],
                [-71.516, 46.437],
                [-71.516, 37.936],
                [-80.425, 37.936]
            ]
        }
    },
    "sprite": "mapbox://sprites/mapbox/dark-v9",
    "glyphs": "mapbox://fonts/mapbox/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
    "layers": [
        {
            "id": "background",
            "type": "background",
            "paint": {"background-color": "#111"}
        },
        {
            "id": "water",
            "source": "mapbox",
            "source-layer": "water",
            "type": "fill",
            "paint": {"fill-color": "#2c2c2c"}
        },
        {
            "id": "boundaries",
            "source": "mapbox",
            "source-layer": "admin",
            "type": "line",
            "paint": {"line-color": "#797979", "line-dasharray": [2, 2, 6, 2]},
            "filter": ["all", ["==", "maritime", 0]]
        },
        {
            "id": "overlay",
            "source": "overlay",
            "type": "raster",
            "paint": {"raster-opacity": 0.85}
        },
        {
            "id": "cities",
            "source": "mapbox",
            "source-layer": "place_label",
            "type": "symbol",
            "layout": {
                "text-field": "{name_en}",
                "text-font": ["DIN Offc Pro Bold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
                "text-size": {"stops": [[4, 9], [6, 12]]}
            },
            "paint": {
                "text-color": "#969696",
                "text-halo-width": 2,
                "text-halo-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "states",
            "source": "mapbox",
            "source-layer": "state_label",
            "type": "symbol",
            "layout": {
                "text-transform": "uppercase",
                "text-field": "{name_en}",
                "text-font": ["DIN Offc Pro Bold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
                "text-letter-spacing": 0.15,
                "text-max-width": 7,
                "text-size": {"stops": [[4, 10], [6, 14]]}
            },
            "filter": [">=", "area", 80000],
            "paint": {
                "text-color": "#969696",
                "text-halo-width": 2,
                "text-halo-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)"
            }
        }
    ]
};

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    maxZoom: 5.99,
    minZoom: 4,
    zoom: 5,
    center: [-75.789, 41.874],
    style: mapStyle,
    hash: false
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have searched around for a while and experimented extensively, however I cannot seem to find a solution or a possible workaround anywhere. As far as I know it is not a CORS error. It would be great if someone could point out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, it still is a CORS issue. The image and the script have to be located on the same domain, or the image has to have appropriate CORS headers. Keep in mind that CORS error does not always give an explicit CORS error, but can also give an error like the above.